# android app not calling webservices

Tags: android, web-services

Hi i have developed an android application, it mainly communicates with my server for registration, logging in etc...   I have completed all my coding , My app is working fine in emulator but when i'm deploying it in my android mobile, app is not connecting to my server
Here is the code i'm using to connect

```
public Object execute(Map<String,String> params,String key,Class typeInfo)throws RestGatewayException
{  
    //httpClient = RestClientConnectionPool.getHttpClient(restHostInfo.isPooolConnections());
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String url = RestRequestMaker.prepareURL(key, params, restHostInfo);
    HttpRequestBase method = RestRequestMaker.prepareHttpMethod(restHostInfo.getRequestMethods().get(key),url);     
    try 
    {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpHost, method);
        if(typeInfo==null)
        {
            return RestResponseHandler.getResponse(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
        else
        {
            String jsonResponse = RestClientUtil.getJSONResponse(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
            return RestResponseHandler.getResponse(jsonResponse, typeInfo);
        }
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        throw new RestGatewayException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        throw new RestGatewayException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
}
```

my app is struck at

```
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpHost, method);
```

Is there any approach while using webservices in case of android? Or is my approach incorrect?

Comment: are you entering the URL correctly ?

Comment: URL :http://192.168.1.13:8080/DishaAPIServer/rest/user?pwd=mani&phone=919739014562&email=manikanta.garikipati%40gmail.com&name=manikanta&state=1&gender=F     It is executing fine when i'm sending it from postman client

Comment: Have you tried to open this URL http://192.168.1.13:8080/DishaAPIServer/rest/user?pwd=mani&phone=919739014562&email=manikanta.garikipati%40gmail.com&name=manikanta&state=1&gender=F with the Android browser.

Comment: Did you checked the URL using Advanced Rest Client extension for chrome ?

Comment: android browser in the sense emulator browser or my mobile browser.